# A problem with this sentence 地球上の四方は人間が生活するために便宜上その概念を使用しているものだが、デジタルワールドではその世界が成り立つ時に東西南北を起点としたグリッドを使用していたのかもしれない。

Tags: reading-comprehension

I was reading a Digimon novel, but I have problems with this sentence.

> デジタルワールドにも東西南北という方向性が存在する。地球上の四方は人間が生活するために便宜上その概念を使用しているものだが、デジタルワールドではその世界が成り立つ時に東西南北を起点としたグリッドを使用していたのかもしれない。

I don't understand what the second sentence says, but I think it is something like: "at first, the four cardinal points were a great place to live in, but then it was divided into different areas.

Comment: Could you quote the Japanese words that are the source for your translation: "*but then it was divided into different areas*"?

Comment: In the digital world, there are the directions such as the east, the west, the south, the north. In the earth we use in convenience the concept of four cardinal points for us to live, in the digital world we might have used the grid which is originated in the four directions when the world was made of.

Comment: Thanks you very much @kimi !
macraf, the source of the first translation was when i try to ask about the sentence to my sensei, but he dont speak very well my native languaje so that was i understand xD

Answer (score 2):

***In the Digital World also, there are all four points of the compass, north, south, east and west.***

***In the earth, in our actual world on the surface of the globe, (there are no such points actually, but) we use them for the convenience for humans to live on.***

***In the Digital World, however, the grid that starts from north, south, east and west might have been settled in advance when the world was created.***

In my opinion, the latter part of the sentence was not well written in Japanese. So there is no wonder for Japanese learners to have difficulty to understand it. I don't like the sentence because it seems illogical from a scientific viewpoint. But I can understand what the writer was trying to say.